# Get a clip's file path from OpenFX Plugin

Tags: rust, openfx

I'm just starting to dabble in OFX Plugin development with Rust, and was wondering if there's a way to get a clip's file path? Obviously OFX Plugins can be used in nodes, transitions, or other places where a clip's file path wouldn't make any sense, but It'd be really useful if there were a way of getting a clip's file path when an OFX Effect is applied directly on a clip in a timeline, for example in DaVinci Resolve. I've had a look through the [ofxPropertiesReference](https://openfx.readthedocs.io/en/master/Reference/ofxPropertiesReference.html#c.kOfxPropLabel), but can't seem to find anything relevant there.

The reason I'm looking to do this is so that I can open a video file in an external application directly through the OFX Plugin's interface.

Comment: Have you ever figured it out? I need the same thing